# How can an HTML page extract parameters passed through a form?

Tags: php, javascript, html

My question is should I convert two html pages to php pages, so the called page can access its POSTed parameters, or is there a way for a called html (.html extension) page to access posted parameters?

I've been reading that because posted parameters are server-side there is no way for JavaScript to do this being client side. I've seen nothing about one html page accessing
parameters if that .html page was accessed via a POST.

Here is my calling form. The called form, needs access to TransDesc (below), which is a text field.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript1.2">

// Check where we came from so that we can go to the right spot when the
// form gets posted from outside of our HTML tree.
var PostURL = '/event.html';

</script>

Enter a Donation Amount
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript1.2">
document.write(
'<form name="InvGenPayDonation" 
action="'+PostURL+'" 
onsubmit="return validateForm();"
method=POST>');
</script>

<p> $ <input type='text' name='Amount' value="0.00">
</p>
<p>In honor of <span style="color: #FF0000">
<input type='text' name='TransDesc' id='TransDesc' value="" >
</p>
<input type="submit" value="Next"> <br /><br />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A static HTML file cannot access variables that have been POST'ed to it. It can't even know they're there as they're sent to the server in the HTTP request, the server then deals with them and sends the HTML page in the HTTP response. They're 'consumed' before the page is even sent to the client.

You could use GET and access them via JavaScript, or configure Apache to server .html files as PHP files instead though.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, php is the easiest way to go, and as far as languages go is pretty easy to learn and pretty intuitive.

Comment: Thanks, but can a called .html page access posted parameters?

Comment: You can configure your webserver to treat files with a .HTML extension as PHP files.

Comment: What andrew said is correct, however the file still would need to be in php format, so if you want to keep the html in the address that is fine, but you need to format the file on your server using $_POST or $_GET

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to either convert them to PHP or use GET instead of POST, as GET parameters are accessible through `window.location.href`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I would recommend converting the pages to php.  If you are set on using HTML files you will have to edit your htaccess file to run HTML pages as php.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use ajax to retrieve and send post and get values.

You can retrieve it with js by creating a php file and access those with ajax from your html files.